# How to implement Search inside of the Picker in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit, maui-windows

I am building a .NET MAUI Android application and I want to implement Search upon selecting something from a Picker (since my Picker component can have more than 100 elements of data).

Does anybody have an idea on how to implement this?

My initial idea was to try to implement Search through the SearchBar component specifically with the TextChanged event, but I had no success.

So I am wondering if is there a whole component that includes Search and the Picker, and if there isn't what do you suggest I do in order to implement search in the picker component?

Comment: if you have more than 100 items to display, a Picker is probably not the best choice.  I'd use a ListView or CollectionView with a searchbar

Comment: You can use the AutoComplete control for this https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

Comment: I had to write a pop-up page include searchbar and listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Jason Comment
I managed to resolve this by creating CollectionView with SearchBar.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Jason's answer, create a view model with `FilterText`, `Words` and `FilteredWords`:

```cs
// MainViewModel.cs
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(FilteredWords))]
    private string _filterText = string.Empty;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<string> _words
        = "the,be,to,of,and,a,in,that,have,I,it,for,not,on,with,he,as,you,do,at,this,but,his,by,from,they,we,say,her,she,or,an,will,my,one,all,would,there,their,what,so,up,out,if,about,who,get,which,go,me,when,make,can,like,time,no,just,him,know,take,people,into,year,your,good,some,could,them,see,other,than,then,now,look,only,come,its,over,think,also,back,after,use,two,how,our,work,first,well,way,even,new,want,because,any,these,give,day,most,u"
          .Split(",").ToList();

    public List<String> FilteredWords
        => FilterText.Length == 0 ? Words : Words.Where(w => w.StartsWith(FilterText)).ToList();
}
```

Then, on your page, create a `TwoWay` binding for `FilteredText` and show the `FilteredWords` in a `ListView`. React to `ItemTapped` events on the `ListView`.

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
    <Entry Text="{Binding FilterText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredWords}"
              ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(MainViewModel VM)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = VM;
    }

    private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Tapped {e.Item}");
    }
}
```